# Rails - Objects not refreshed after Saving or Deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord, insert-update, destroy

I am doing some saving and destroying operation on a object which behaves weird.

```
  if already_in_server
        bookmark_obj = array_already_bookmarked.detect {|bookmark| bookmark.article_doi == article_doi["doi"]}
        if 1 == article_doi["isbookmarked"]
          binding.pry
          bookmark_obj.updated_at = Time.now
          bookmark_obj.save
        else
          bookmark_obj.destroy
        end
 end
```

Association between them:

```
up has_many -----> bookmarks
bookmark belongs_to --> up
```

But when I try to call up.bookmarks, It also returns destroyed objects and

```
bookmark_obj.updated_at = Time.now
```

is not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Reload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload) which will reloads the record from the database.
so after you save record you can do:

```
if already_in_server
    bookmark_obj = array_already_bookmarked.detect {|bookmark| bookmark.article_doi == article_doi["doi"]}
    if 1 == article_doi["isbookmarked"]
      binding.pry
      bookmark_obj.updated_at = Time.now
      bookmark_obj.save
      bookmark_obj.reload   # Add this line
    else
      bookmark_obj.destroy
    end
end
```

and in case of deleted then you will need to reload the other relation, as you mentioned `up` has_many `bookmarks`

```
bookmark_obj.destroy
up.bookmarks # this one will contain the destroyed bookmark 
up.reload    # reload to retrieve fresh list
up.bookmarks # will not contain the destroyed bookmark
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload object by adding `bookmark_obj.reload` after `bookmark_obj.save`

```
bookmark_obj.save
bookmark_obj.reload
```

In case of `destroy`, `reload` the parent object

```
parent_obj.reload
parent_obj.bookmarks
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: after destroy? can you help in that too?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't confirm previous solutions, I assume it didn't worked.

I've noticed that you use "safe" versions of methods `save` and `delete`, so maybe updates and deletes just doesn't happen because of your validators of callbacks fails? Have you checked danger versions like `save!` and `delete!`?